# add trace in loop deletes previous traces in R shiny

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, r-plotly

I have tried these 3 solutions mentioned in the link 
[Plotly: add_trace in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34186560/plotly-add-trace-in-a-loop)

but my code is still not working, the code shows only the final trace in the loop.

```
output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    if(input$x == "M"){
      my_x <- c(input$mmin:input$mmax)
      number_of_cpgs <- 500*my_x
      timetaken <- rep(0,input$mmax-input$mmin +1)
      p<-plot_ly(y= timetaken, x= (number_of_cpgs) ,type="scatter", mode="markers+lines")
      for(i in input$nmin:input$nmax){
        for(j in input$kmin:input$kmax){
          timetaken <- timemat[i,my_x,j]
          p<-add_trace(p, y=~timemat[i,my_x,j], x=~(number_of_cpgs) , type="scatter",mode="markers+lines",visible = TRUE )
        }
      }
    }
```

[image]

Reproducible example:

```
timemat <- array(c(1:1000), dim=c(10, 10, 10)) 
my_x <- c(1:10) 
number_of_cpgs <- 500*my_x 
timetaken <- rep(0,10) 
p<-plot_ly(y= timetaken, x= (number_of_cpgs) ,type="scatter", mode="markers+lines") 
for(i in 5:6){ 
  for(j in 6:7){ 
    timetaken <- timemat[i,my_x,j] 
p <- add_trace(p, y=~timemat[i,my_x,j], x=~(number_of_cpgs) , type="scatter", mode="markers+lines", evaluate = TRUE) 
  }
  } 
p
```

Comment: As suggested in the answer, have you tried to add `evaluate = TRUE` in `add_trace`?

Comment: Yeah i also tried that

Comment: Without a reprodicible example, it is hard to tell.

Comment: Can you please suggest edit with this code

Comment: library(plotly)

timemat <- array(c(1:1000), dim=c(10, 10, 10))

my_x <- c(1:10)
number_of_cpgs <- 500*my_x
timetaken <- rep(0,10)
p<-plot_ly(y= timetaken, x= (number_of_cpgs) ,type="scatter", mode="markers+lines")

for(i in 5:6){
  for(j in 6:7){
    timetaken <- timemat[i,my_x,j]
    p<-add_trace(p, y=~timemat[i,my_x,j], x=~(number_of_cpgs) , type="scatter",mode="markers+lines",visible = TRUE )
  }
}
p

Comment: Your code is working but trace 1 to trace 4 are on top of each other. Unselect some of your trace and you will see it.

Comment: it is no working, it is just changing colours, you can verify by printing timemat[5,8,6] and timemat[6,8,6] both HAVE DIFFERENT VALUES, SO HOW CAN THEY OVERLAP IN PLOT ?

Comment: In your loop, why is `timetaken <- timemat[i,my_x,j]` is the same as your y, `y=~timemat[i,my_x,j]`?

Comment: i was just trying to use them, to see if data is being overwritten

Comment: I had the same problem: Removing "~" inside add_trace resolved the issue: `add_trace(p, y=timemat[i,my_x,j], x=(number_of_cpgs) , type="scatter", mode="markers+lines", evaluate = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you are looking for?

```
p<-plot_ly(y= timetaken, x= (number_of_cpgs) ,type="scatter", mode="markers+lines") 
for(i in 5:6){ 
  for(j in 6:7){ 
   # timetaken <- timemat[i,my_x,7] 
  testing = timemat[i,my_x,j]
p <- add_trace(p, y=testing, x=~(number_of_cpgs) , type="scatter", mode="markers+lines", evaluate = TRUE) 
  }
  } 
p
```

[image]

Comment: yeah i am looking for something like this, but if you see you have added 5 traces but only final trace of add_trace loop has been added

Comment: I see 4 different traces